sliding tile problem using hill climbing algorithm
I'm trying to solve sliding tile problem using hill climbing algorithm. I have wrote the code to print each intermediate step until i reach goal node but the code is return a memory address instead.
from copy import deepcopy

class State:
    def __init__(self, state):
        goal_state = [[1, 2, 3], [8, 0, 4], [7, 6, 5]]
        self.state = state
        self.cost = self.calculate_cost(goal_state)


    def calculate_cost(self, goal_state):

        cost = 0

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.state[i][j] != goal_state[i][j]:
                    cost += 1

        return cost


    def generate_neighbors(self):
        neighbors = []

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.state[i][j] == 0:

                    new_state = deepcopy(self.state)

                    if i >= 0 and i != 2:   #move down
                        new_state[i][j], new_state[i+1][j] = new_state[i+1][j], new_state[i][j]
                        neighbors.append(State(new_state))

                    if i <=2 and i != 0:    #move up
                        new_state[i][j], new_state[i-1][j] = new_state[i-1][j], new_state[i][j]
                        neighbors.append(State(new_state))

                    if j >= 0 and j != 2: # move right
                        new_state[i][j], new_state[i][j+1] = new_state[i][j+1], new_state[i][j]
                        neighbors.append(State(new_state))

                    if j <= 2 and j != 0:   # move left
                        new_state[i][j], new_state[i][j-1] = new_state[i][j-1], new_state[i][j]
                        neighbors.append(State(new_state))


        return neighbors

def hill_climbing(initial_state):

    current_state = initial_state

    while True:
        neighbors = current_state.generate_neighbors()
        best_neighbor = min(neighbors, key = lambda state: state.cost)

        if best_neighbor.cost <= current_state.cost:
            print(best_neighbor)
            break

        print(current_state)
        current_state = best_neighbor


initial_state = State([[2, 0, 3], [1, 8, 4], [7, 6, 5]])

hill_climbing(initial_state)

Output:
<__main__.State object at 0x0000021FE103FEE0>


Implement def __repr__(self): so Python knows how to print a State object.

i am not familiar with this function can you elaborate it please

Define __repr__ or __str__ in a custom class

Difference between __repr__ and __str__

if you need to see some value (without creating __str__ or __repr__) then you have to get it directly like print( current_state.state, current_state.cost )

Python does not know how to print your State object so it returns just a memory address
You can add a __repr__ method to your State class that will return a formatted string of you class state. Here is an example (you need to add to your class):
def __repr__(self):
    # Create a readable string for the state
    return '\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in self.state])

__repr__ method formats the state as a string where each row is on a new line and numbers are separated by spaces. Once you print a State object (just as you do now), it will display a nice formatted string instead of memory address
Here are 2 related stackoverflow discussions that can be helpful as well: one and two
